# Use an SSRS multi-value parameter in a SQL query without using the IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have to pass multiple values (eg: Year1, year2, year3, etc.) to the same query, but I cannot use the IN condition as I'm using less than or equal to in most of the cases. Can I do this by passing multiple values through the same parameter without changing the query?

Is it possible to get multiple values from an SSRS parameter and pass them on to the query to get the output as:

```
Year1           Year2           Year3
Value(output)   Value(output)   Value(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the multi-value parameter as a comma separated string but your SQL query is going to need updating to handle that CSV string. In order to pass the multi-value parameter as a CSV string you would open the dataset properties and go to the parameters tab. Then set the value of your parameter to this expresssion:

```
=JOIN(Parameters!MultiValueYearParameter.Value,",")
```

This will join all of the values in the multivalue parameter together and use a comma as the delimiter. You can then process this using the split function below (or just modify it to work inline in your SQL if you either cannot or don't need to create a separate function to do this).

This blog post on a [Split Function for T-SQL using FOR XML](http://blog.codelab.co.nz/2009/07/29/split-function-for-t-sql-using-xml/) shows how to do this without using string parsing or a while loop. String parsing is prone to error and isn't scalable and while loops should just be avoided in SQL whenever possible.

Below I've modified the split function to return a table of `DATE` values that you can then use in an `INNER JOIN` to filter your query using whatever operators you like.

```sql
--this is the parameter passed from the report
--(the date strings may not be formatted this way. do not try to rely on that)
DECLARE @YearParameter VARCHAR(MAX) = '2014-01-01,2011-12-02,2015-10-22';


--use this to do the xml parsing
declare @xml xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@YearParameter,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

--create a table variable to store the date values
DECLARE @dateValues TABLE (val DATE);

--parse the xml/csv string and cast the results to a DATE and insert into the table var
INSERT INTO @dateValues
select CAST(r.value('.','varchar(max)') AS DATE) AS val
from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r);
```

You can then use that table variable to filter your SQL query. I've given an example of how to use it below.

In the example I create a table of rows with a start and end date. Then I filter that table to show only rows where a parameter value is between the start and end date.

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (Descript VARCHAR(25), startDate DATE, endDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @testTable (Descript, startDate, endDate)
    VALUES ('row1', '2014-05-01','2014-08-01'), ('row2', '2013-10-01','2014-01-10'), ('row3', '2015-10-01','2015-12-15'),('row4','2013-01-01','2015-01-01'),
        --these rows won't appear in the result set
            ('row5','2010-01-01','2010-06-01'), ('row6','2013-12-25','2014-05-20');


-- get all rows from the test table where a selected parameter value
-- is between the start and end dates.
SELECT *
FROM @testTable AS tbl
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @dateValues
    WHERE val BETWEEN tbl.startDate AND tbl.endDate
);
```

Comment: Also consider dynamic sql:  turning the multi-valued parameter into a series of `UNION SELECT`s, using the `REPLACE` function.  `SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE (@ProductParam,',',''' UNION SELECT ''') + ''''`  Then the dynamic sql is executed after an `INSERT`, to load the table variable.  Link on this:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23252.ssrs-easy-way-to-split-multi-parameter-values-in-sql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS you can build tables and complex solutions.
In the Text Query of report builder here is an example of splitting apart a parameter to get three dates.

```
BEGIN 

/* suppose the inbound pram is a string with 10 places per date '01/01/2010,11/12/2012,05/06/2013' */
/* you could also nip the string apart by each comma... */

DECLARE @YEAR1 DATETIME 
DECLARE @YEAR2 DATETIME 
DECLARE @YEAR3 DATETIME

SET  @YEAR1 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@INBOUNDPARAM, 1, 10) AS DATETIME)
SET  @YEAR2 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@INBOUNDPARAM, 12, 10) AS DATETIME)
SET  @YEAR3 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@INBOUNDPARAM, 23, 10) AS DATETIME)

SELECT  @YEAR1 AS Year1, @YEAR2 AS Year2, @YEAR3 AS Year3

END
```

Of course the Year of the date is just   YEAR(@Year1) = 2010 for example...